# Send FCM notification to multiple tokens using Plokko Firebase

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the Plokko FCM v1 library: https://github.com/plokko/php-fcm-v1

so far i am using a loop to send to multiple tokens, and it is becoming too slow as each loop is waiting for the notification to be sent, how to send to multiple tokens at once like we used to do it in legacy HTTP code.

i tried making it an array, a comma seperated value both times i am getting

> The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token

any help would be appriciated

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must use `registration_ids` instead of to in creating an object and make an array of devices token and assign it to `registration_ids` as follow

```js
const id = deviceIds;
      
      const Title = "Title";
      const message = "This is testing notification";

      
      const messaged = {
         registration_ids: id,        //// multiple devices  
         // to: id,                  //// use for single device 
         collapse_key: 'appName',
         notification: {
             title:Title, 
             body: message 
         }
      };

     await fcm.send(messaged, function(err, response){
         if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            // result(null,{success:false,message:"Some Error", data:err});
         } else {
            console.log(response)
         }
      });
```